# hibernate evict cascade in complex reference situation behavior

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Three entities: A, B, C. A and B has a collection data member can hold multiple C, for example, object a contain c1 & c2, object b contain c1 (with DETACH cascade type).

First persist them to database according to above description, then get a & b from session(c1 & c2 are load eagerly). Then evict b object, due to the DETACH cascade, c1 also should be evict. However, c1 also hold by object a. Should it be evict or not? Whatever hibernate do, it seems inconsistent

I have not found any doc about this situation.

Comment: What is your actual question? What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: I need to manually control session cache by evict or detach

Answer (score 0):

I step into hibernate code found when detach object b, 2 objects(b,c1) will be detached from session whether or not c1 still hold by object a. And the re-attach of c1 object to session will not trigger an select SQL operation, it seems hibernate session keep c1 snapshot data in another place even it already detached